# subtracting square wave from csv values

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file of time and resistance values with non-periodic pulses I need to remove.

This is what I'm trying but can't make the list elements into floats to do the comparison.

```
import csv

f=open('sample.csv')
csv_f=csv.reader(f)

res = []

next(csv_f)

for row in csv_f:
    res.append([float(row[1])])

l = len(res)
previous = current = None

for i, r in enumerate(res):
    if i > 0:
        current = float(res[i])
        previous = float(res[i-1])
        dif = current-previous
        if dif > 1:
            res[i] = res[i] - dif
```

ideally I'd like to continue to subtract this difference until I detect another edge indicating the end of the pulse

with this code I get this error trying to cast the list element as a float

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

if I remove the cast then it says

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: If you're looking for edge detection, you may want to check out [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).  Other than that, I'm not sure what you're saying your problem is.  Please edit your question to tell us your exact error, and what line it occurs on.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I'll take a look. I also edited my post to include the errors I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a few too many conversions going on.  Honestly, the best thing that would have helped you is finding out

```
type(res[i])
```

(either through the interactive shell or a debugger like pdb).

You probably think `res[i]` is a float, but instead, it's a list.  Here's why.

```
res.append([float(row[1])])
```

This line is appending into res, a (single-element) list consisting of the float value from row[1].  If you look at res (i.e. `print(res)`), you'll see something like this: `[[1.2], [2.3], [3.14], [1.714]]`, when what I expect you want is simply `[1.2, 2.3, 3.14, 1.714]`.

To fix this, just remove the square brackets:

```
res.append(float(row[1]))
```

Once you do this, you don't need any of your other float conversions:

```
import csv

f=open('sample.csv')
csv_f=csv.reader(f)

res = []

next(csv_f)

for row in csv_f:
    res.append(float(row[1]))

l = len(res)
previous = current = None

for i, r in enumerate(res):
    if i > 0:
        current = res[i]
        previous = res[i-1]
        dif = current-previous
        if dif > 1:
            res[i] = res[i] - dif
```

Comment: Excellent, this gets me back to making progress. Thanks Scott!